# Workaround for EKParcipant URL accessing crash?

Tags: swift, swift3

Some of my users have been sent me logs identifying a `EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)` Error on this line of code. I've been been trying to make it safe but all of the properties of `EKParticipant` are non optional so comparing to nil just gives me a warning saying it will always be true. If something is nil here how should I handle it?

**Error Line**

```
let participantEmail : String? = participant.url.absoluteString.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: "mailto:", with: "")
```

**Apple Error Description**

> Trace Trap [EXC_BREAKPOINT // SIGTRAP]
>
> Similar to an Abnormal Exit, this exception is intended to give an
>   attached debugger the chance to interrupt the process at a specific
>   point in its execution. You can trigger this exception from your own
>   code using the __builtin_trap() function. If no debugger is attached,
>   the process is terminated and a crash report is generated. Lower-level
>   libraries (e.g, libdispatch) will trap the process upon encountering a
>   fatal error. Additional information about the error can be found in
>   the Additional Diagnostic Information section of the crash report, or
>   in the device's console. Swift code will terminate with this exception
>   type if an unexpected condition is encountered at runtime such as:
>       a non-optional type with a nil value
>       a failed forced type conversion Look at the Backtraces to determine where the unexpected condition was encountered. Additional
>   information may have also been logged to the device's console. You
>   should modify the code at the crashing location to gracefully handle
>   the runtime failure. For example, use Optional Binding instead of
>   force unwrapping an optional."

**Full Method**

```
    /**
Parses participants for a given event.
 Goes through the EKEvents attendees array to build Attendee objects used to model a participant.

 - parameter event: The calendar event we'll be finding the participants for.
 - returns: An array of Attendee objects with the participants name, email, required/optional status and whether they've accepted their invitation to the event.
 */
private static func parseParticipantsIn(event: EKEvent) -> [Attendee] {
var participants = [Attendee]()

if let attendees = event.attendees, event.attendees?.isEmpty == false {
    for participant in attendees {
        let participantName : String? = parse(EKParticipantName: participant)
            let participantEmail : String? = participant.url.absoluteString.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: "mailto:", with: "")

            let isRequiredParticipant : Bool = participant.participantRole == EKParticipantRole.required
            let hasAccepted : Bool = participant.participantStatus == EKParticipantStatus.accepted

             guard (participantName != nil && participantEmail !=  nil)
                else
            {
                log.error("Participant could not be parsed")
                continue
            }
            let attendee = Attendee(name: participantName!, email: participantEmail!, required: isRequiredParticipant, hasAccepted: hasAccepted)
            participants.append(attendee)
        }
    }
    return participants
}
```

Comment: Is this about `NRURL`'s `absoluteString` returns optional `String`?

`let participantEmail : String? = url.absoluteString?.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: "mailto:", with: "")`

Comment: @SunilChauhan I've tried that but I get an error saying `cannot use optional chaining on non optional value of 'String'`.

Comment: Then there should be some thing related to swift version. Which version are you on? 2.2 I guess.

Comment: @SunilChauhan 3.1

Comment: Strange. Mine is swift 3.0 and can't compile unless I put `?` with `absoluteString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with the `EKParticipant.url` property. Any attempted access of `EKParticipant.url` causes a crash if you have a participant with the following email field within it.

`"Bill Gates" <billgates@google.com>`

I'd guess the quotation marks end the String prematurely. It is fine when accessed from `EKParticipant.description` so I intend to parse it from there.

Comment: please, report a bug too.

Answer (score 1):

This is a ridiculous issue, and Deco pinpointed it exactly.  I used a different approach to get around it though: Since I'm already working in a mixed code base (obj-c and Swift), I created a class method on one of my obj-c classes that takes an EKParticipant and returns its URL as a string.  Then, in Swift, I call that class method to get the URL instead of directly accessing the property (and crashing).  It's hacky, but better than crashing and saved me from parsing the description.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather old question but yet I hit this issue myself. My solution is to fallback to ObjC in order to workaround it.

Just add this ObjC functions to swift bridging header file and you are good to use them in swift.

```
static inline BOOL
participantHasNonNilURL (EKParticipant* _Nonnull  participant) {
    return participant.URL != nil;
}

static inline NSURL* _Nullable
participantURL(EKParticipant* _Nonnull  participant) {
    if (participant.URL != nil) {
        return participant.URL;
    }else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
extension EKParticipant {
    var optionalURL: URL? {
        return participantURL(self)
    }

    var hasURL: Bool {
        return participantHasNonNilURL(self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue on macOS 11.2... I have [reported](https://github.com/feedback-assistant/reports/issues/189) it to Apple. I encourage anyone else hitting this issue to do the same.

The only Swift-only workaround that worked for me is:

```swift
extension EKParticipant {
    public var safeURL: URL? {
        perform(#selector(getter: EKParticipant.url))?.takeUnretainedValue() as? NSURL? as? URL
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Validations are added incorrectly, please check the below response about how the guard could be used.

```
if let attendees = event.attendees, event.attendees?.isEmpty == false {
    for participant in attendees {
        guard let participantName : String? = parse(EKParticipantName: participant) else{ 
              log.error("error in participant name")
              return
          }
        guard let participantEmail : String? = participant.url.absoluteString.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: "mailto:", with: "") else{ 
              log.error("error in participant email")
              return
          }

       let isRequiredParticipant : Bool = participant.participantRole == EKParticipantRole.required
       let hasAccepted : Bool = participant.participantStatus == EKParticipantStatus.accepted

       /* guard validation is not required here */
       if (participantName != nil && participantEmail !=  nil){
            let attendee = Attendee(name: participantName!, email: participantEmail!, required: isRequiredParticipant, hasAccepted: hasAccepted)
            participants.append(attendee)
       }
    }
}
return participants
```

Comment: I'll give it a try thanks.
I do have a warning on the line of the guard statements saying `Explicitly specified type 'String?' adds an additional level of optional to the initializer, making the optional check always succeed. What does this mean?